# How to parse JSON with shell scripting for braces edge case

Tags: linux, json

I have a JSON output from which I need to extract a few parameters in Linux.

This is the JSON output:

```
{
  items:[
    {
      provider_name:"ucp-ipg",
      subject_name:"rtm-instrumentation",
      dataset_name:"rtm-instrumentation-dataset-hour-sliced",
      dataset_key:[
        2018-03-06T06:00:00Z,
        "000394e3-a9eb-40b6-9463-fbd588d20ba4"
      ],
      record_count:21,
      state:"complete",
      version:0,
      etag:"a221df62",
      creation_timestamp:2018-03-06T06:10:46.294-00:00,
      created_by:"AAA",
      modification_timestamp:2018-03-06T06:10:46.294-00:00,
      modified_by:"AAA"
    },
    {
      provider_name:"ucp-ipg",
      subject_name:"rtm-instrumentation",
      dataset_name:"rtm-instrumentation-dataset-hour-sliced",
      dataset_key:[
        2018-03-06T06:00:00Z,
        "00097722-b02f-4938-bd4b-d935047c3837"
      ],
      record_count:17,
      state:"complete",
      version:0,
      etag:"aa4dbc25",
      creation_timestamp:2018-03-06T06:12:23.293-00:00,
      created_by:"AAA",
      modification_timestamp:2018-03-06T06:12:23.293-00:00,
      modified_by:"AAA"
    }
```

I want the output of

```
dataset_key:[
        2018-03-06T06:00:00Z,
        "00097722-b02f-4938-bd4b-d935047c3837"
      ]
```

---

I have already tried with below but not working :

```
file.txt | python -mjson.tool | grep 'dataset_key'
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a well formed JSON document. The keys are not quoted and some of the data is not quoted.

Comment: And not only are the keys not quoted, the dates (if they are supposed to be strings) are also not quoted. So the first step would be to get whatever produces this output to produce proper JSON, so you can use JSON tools like `jq` on it.

Comment: You are mixing json processing and grep processing: the `python -mjson.tool` just passes the input to the output, and grep works one one line at a time. You need to tell the json tool to do the grepping.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the JSON document is well formed and complete, as for example

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "provider_name": "ucp-ipg",
      "subject_name": "rtm-instrumentation",
      "dataset_name": "rtm-instrumentation-dataset-hour-sliced",
      "dataset_key": [
        "2018-03-06T06:00:00Z",
        "000394e3-a9eb-40b6-9463-fbd588d20ba4"
      ],
      "record_count": 21,
      "state": "complete",
      "version": 0,
      "etag": "a221df62",
      "creation_timestamp": "2018-03-06T06:10:46.294-00:00",
      "created_by": "AAA",
      "modification_timestamp": "2018-03-06T06:10:46.294-00:00",
      "modified_by": "AAA"
    },
    {
      "provider_name": "ucp-ipg",
      "subject_name": "rtm-instrumentation",
      "dataset_name": "rtm-instrumentation-dataset-hour-sliced",
      "dataset_key": [
        "2018-03-06T06:00:00Z",
        "00097722-b02f-4938-bd4b-d935047c3837"
      ],
      "record_count": 17,
      "state": "complete",
      "version": 0,
      "etag": "aa4dbc25",
      "creation_timestamp": "2018-03-06T06:12:23.293-00:00",
      "created_by": "AAA",
      "modification_timestamp": "2018-03-06T06:12:23.293-00:00",
      "modified_by": "AAA"
    }
  ]
}
```

The second `item` element's `dataset_key` array may be had with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq '.items[1].dataset_key' file.json
[
  "2018-03-06T06:00:00Z",
  "00097722-b02f-4938-bd4b-d935047c3837"
]
```

Change `[1]` to `[-1]` to get the `dataset_key` from the *last* `item` element.

To get the raw data of the array elements:

```
$ jq -r '.items[1].dataset_key[]' file.json
2018-03-06T06:00:00Z
00097722-b02f-4938-bd4b-d935047c3837
```

Comment: @user3256289: If this works for you, then the example you gave in your question doesn't match your actual data, because AFAIK `jq` doesn't parse malformed JSON. So, please include the correct data the next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot make the json valid, e.g. for an output of an API you have no control of, this will return your desired output:

```
perl -0777 -ne '/(dataset_key:\[[^\]]*\])/ && print "$1\n"' file.txt
```

> Note: This would break if the item contained a `]`.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to extract info from json is *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)* (assuming your json is fixed):

```
bash $ jtc -w '<dataset_key>l+0' -r your.json 
[ "2018-03-06T06:00:00Z", "000394e3-a9eb-40b6-9463-fbd588d20ba4" ]
[ "2018-03-06T06:00:00Z", "00097722-b02f-4938-bd4b-d935047c3837" ]
bash $
```